# Breakpoint not hit when method called in lambda

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, debugging, .net-3.5

When I put a breakpoint in a method I'm calling from a lambda expression, the breakpoint is never hit.  When I move the method call outside the lambda, the breakpoint hits.

For example:

```
Function IncrementAll(ByVal items As IEnumerable(Of Integer)) As IEnumerable(Of Integer)
  Return items.Select(Function(i) Increment(i))
End Function

Function Increment(ByVal i As Integer) As Integer
  Return i + 1 'Breakpoint here
End Function
```

If I call IncrementAll, the breakpoint in Increment does not get hit.  Is there a way to make VS 2008 stop on these breakpoints?  I hate the thought of rewriting all my LINQ into loops just for debugging.

Comment: Interesting, I know I've done this in .NET 4.  You've verified that there are elements in "items", and that you are running in a debug configuration (ie, breakpoints will be hit elsewhere in the project)?

Comment: Yep, if I put a breakpoint on items.Select above it will hit, and if I convert items.Select to a loop, then the breakpoint in Increment will hit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I figured it out.  The Select returns an IEnumerable, and the actual execution of Increment on each item is deferred until you try to access an item in the IEnumerable.  The quickest way to get the desired effect would be this:

```
Function IncrementAll(ByVal items As IEnumerable(Of Integer)) As IEnumerable(Of Integer)
    Return items.Select(Function(i) Increment(i)).ToList()
End Function
```

The ToList() immediately enumerates, thus executing Increment on each element, and your breakpoint will fire.

Comment: That was it.  The breakpoint was working, but it would only hit long after I was thinking it would, and I wasn't letting it run to that point.  Thanks :)